# When the method __post_init__ doesnt called?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, overriding, python-dataclasses

I found the [issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/90913) where was conversation about an explict call of parent's `__post_init__` method using `super()`, but if I try this:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class A:
    def __post_init__(self):
        print("A")


@dataclass
class B(A):
    pass


b = B()
```

it will output:

```
A
```

So, parents method works without explict call.

1. I don't understand what talk about was in this issue or problem with inheritence was solved?
2. In which case `__post_init__` method of dataclass doesnt called?

Comment: `super().__post_init__` would be needed *inside* `B.__post_init__` if you defined `B.__post_init__` and still needed `A.__post_init__` to be called. As is, `B` simply uses `A.__post_init__` as inherited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue under discussion is in how `__init__` and `__post_init__` differ.

`object` defines `__init__`; it doesn't do anything, but that means it's always safe to call `super().__init__` in your own definitions of `__init__`. You have to take care what *arguments* you pass to it, but the attribute lookup itself will always succeed.

`object` does *not* define `__post_init__`, so calling `super().__post_init__` requires you to know whether at least one class in your MRO will define it, or that you check for it first, or you'll get an `AttributeError`.

So `__post_init__`, if defined, will *always* be called, but it's not safe to assume for explicit `super().__post_init__` calls that the method exists.

Comment: Our answers complement each other nicely. You answered OP's first question while I tackled the second.

Answer (score 4):

By default, the `dataclass` decorator generates an `__init__` method which does the following (among other things):

- Accepts input arguments based on the field definitions in the current and parent classes
- Initializes the attributes of `self` from input arguments
- Calls `self.__post_init__`

Python's inheritance works such that if a parent class has an attribute, the child inherits it unless told otherwise. That's sort of the point.

To disable inheritance, you must override it somehow. The pythoic approach to disabling an inherited method entirely is to set it to `None` in the child class:

```
@dataclass
class B(A):
    __post_init__ = None
```

You can find this technique in the documentation of [`NotImplementedError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NotImplementedError), which you should not be using here:

> **Note:** It [`NotImplementedError`] should not be used to indicate that an operator or method is not meant to be supported at all – in that case either leave the operator / method undefined or, if a subclass, set it to `None`.

In fact, any time the child class overrides a method, the parent implementation won't be called unless explicitly told to do so.

In other words, setting the child's method to `None` is roughly equivalent to

```
@dataclass
class B(A):
    def __post_init__(self):
        pass
```

While leaving the name out of the child class is very roughly equivalent to

```
@dataclass
class B(A):
    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__post_init__()
```

By not calling `super().__post_init__()` from within the child implementation, you prevent the parent implementation from ever being executed.